# Partial sum in Standard ML?

Tags: list, functional-programming, sum, partial, sml

Im new to functional programming and I have an assignment to compute partial sum of a list. 
E.g. 
- psum [1,1,1,1,1];
val it = [1,2,3,4,5] : int list

Here is the my code so far. However in function psum2[L] i dont know how to go through each value and add them up so I just print the list.

```
fun psum2(L) : int list = 
   if L=nil then []
   else L;

fun pSum(L) : int list = 
   psum2(L);

exception Empty_List;

psum([2,3,4]);
```

Comment: Hint: this function is often known as `scan` or `scanl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little broad, but here's one way to sum a list.  Perhaps you can adapt it to your purposes:

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (h::t) = h + sum t
```