# Partial sum in functional programming (recursion)

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partial sum in Standard ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388412/partial-sum-in-standard-ml)

Im new to functional programming and I have an assignment to compute partial sum of a list. E.g. - psum [1,1,1,1,1]; val it = [1,2,3,4,5] : int list

Here is the my code so far. However my function just returns the list as it is.

```
 fun ppsum2([])=[]
| ppsum2(x::L) = x::ppsum2(L);


 exception Empty_List;

fun psum(L) : int list = 
if L=nil then raise Empty_List
else psum2(L);


psum([2,3,4]);
```

Comment: Surely your code is indented like that? :( Anyway, consider `[] -> []` to avoid exceptions entirely. Then, consider the base case and the termination case for the recursive function, and what the result for each step should be, given the input.

Comment: You say "sum", but you haven't used `+` at all. Try evaluating `ppsum2 [2,3,4]` by hand on paper and you'll see why you get an identical list back.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I hope this is simple enough:

```
 fun psum2 [] total = []  
   | psum2 (h::t) total = (total+h) :: psum2 t (total+h)

 fun psum lst = psum2 lst 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the source code for Haskells `scanl1` function, and translate it to ML.

This way, you do not learn functional programming, but media competence.